# Why doesn't IChannelFactory<T> define a parameter-less CreateChannel?

Tags: .net, wcf

Why doesn't the [IChannelFactory< TChannel>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms405876.aspx) interface define a parameter-less [CreateChannel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195321.aspx)?

The concerete [ChannelFactory< TChannel>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) class on the other hand **does** have a parameter-less [CreateChannel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575250.aspx).

For testability/SoC reasons I want to pass around `IChannelFactory` interface but that forces me to also pass around an `EndpointAddress` for use in `CreateChannel(EndpointAddress)`.

As a workaround I have created a `IChannelFactory2< IChannel>` which does have a parameter-less `CreateChannel()`.

But ultimately I'm just curious as to why it was designed like this (generally WCF has reasonable design choices, but Im just too lazy to work this one out alone!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ChannelFactory<T>.CreateChannel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575250.aspx) method **is just a helper method, made possible by an implementation detail** of the [ChannelFactory<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) class.

If you look at the [ChannelFactory<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) source code, you'll see this:

```
public TChannel CreateChannel()
{
    return this.CreateChannel(this.CreateEndpointAddress(this.Endpoint), (Uri) null);
}
```

The `CreateEndpointAddress` method is implemented internally by the abstract [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channelfactory.aspx) class, which [ChannelFactory<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) inherits from:

```
internal EndpointAddress CreateEndpointAddress(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
{
    if (endpoint.Address == (EndpointAddress) null)
        throw DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelperError((Exception) new InvalidOperationException(System.ServiceModel.SR.GetString("SFxChannelFactoryEndpointAddressUri")));
    else
        return endpoint.Address;
}
```

As you can see, the endpoint information is already available through the [ChannelFactory<T>.Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channelfactory.endpoint.aspx) property, which is initialized through [the various constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585866.aspx) of the [ChannelFactory<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) class. These **constructors, in fact, allow the consumers to specify the details of the endpoint to invoke**.

Since interfaces cannot define constructors, the most appropriate way to pass that required piece of information is through the arguments of the method that is going to use it, that is the [CreateChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195571.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.

My solution was using a factory pattern -

```
public interface IFactory<out T>
{
    T CreateInstance();
}

public class WCFChannelFactory<TService> : IFactory<TService>
{
    public ChannelFactory<TService> ChannelFactory { get; set; }

    public WCFChannelFactory(ChannelFactory<TService> channelFactory)
    {
        ChannelFactory = channelFactory;
    }

    public TService CreateInstance()
    {
        return ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
    }
}
```

Then in my application I just use `IFactory`.

Comment: yeah identical to my solution :) but really im curious as to why its the way it is, as opposed to a workaround. cheers